# Kendo Grid: Data Toolbar search function not working within custom SharePoint page

Tags: datatables, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, customization, sharepoint-online

Currently struggling with trying to update a SharePoint custom page with a search bar. The page consists of a data table with various columns, the idea is to add extra functionality to this data table without compromising the code already there.

The main issue is the code not rendering "search" when added to the following area after "excel":

```
data-toolbar='[
    { template: "<a class=\"k-button k-primary\" data-bind=\"click: onCustomCreate, visible: canAdd\">Add New Organisation</a>" },
    { name: "clearAllSorting", text: "Clear All Sorting", attr: "data-bind=\"click: onClearAllSorting\""},
    { name: "clearAllFilters", text: "Clear All Filters", attr: "data-bind=\"click: onClearAllFilters\""},
    "excel"
]'
```

I have put in "pdf" to test, and it renders the Export to PDF button OK:
[PDF button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8nL3.png)

When I add "search" it just shows a box with lower case s for search:
[Search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg33F.png)

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, is it simply missing a more up-to-date kendo library?

Ultimately, all I need is for this to show: [Search toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r83gK.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://www.telerik.com/forums/search-panel-and-toolbar-template

Comment: That definitely points me in the right direction thanks! Just need to find the right library that contains the Search update in the toolbar now.